# Копировать строку из одной таблицы в другую, с лишним столбцом

Tags: mysql, insert

Необходимо скопировать строку из table1 в table2, структура которой такая же, за исключением первых двух столбцов - NN(ключ,автоинкремент) и comments, в который надо записать пояснение.

```
INSERT INTO `table2` (comments,id,current_time,user_name)
VALUES ('текст пояснения',
SELECT id,current_time,user_name
FROM `table1` WHERE id=168)
```

Типа такого, но это не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
INSERT INTO `table2` (comments, id, current_time, user_name)
SELECT 'текст пояснения', id, current_time, user_name
FROM `table1` 
WHERE id = 168
```